# Android restart activity (with AsyncTask) on completion of another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, kill, onresume

I suppose the title is a bit confusing but here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a class called `ManageClass` which lists the entries of a database. I have written another private class within `ManageClass` which extends `AsyncTask` so that I can display a progress dialog while I'm getting the data from the database. Now when I click on an item I create a new Intent which takes me to my `ViewItem` class. I've added a button there so that the user can delete that particular entry that he/she is looking at. All of the above work fine.

Now I want after deleting that entry to kill the activity and go back to the previous one (the one displaying the list) but I want to refresh the listings.

My problem is that I cant use `onResume()` cause it will also be called when the activity is resumed after the `AsyncTask` finishes.

Could anyone help me with that? I'm really stuck... all ideas are welcome!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your app workflow you should use `startActivityForResult` instead of launching a new Activity via intent.

Look at [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen) fore some example

Basically you can launch a new Activity and wait for a result via callback on the "opener" activity. so you can avoid to put your logic into `onResume` method

Comment: Oh yeah...Cheers for that...i just had a quick look at it and...yeah I think that it might work..unfortunately i've been coding since 15.00 yesterday and I'm in no position to test it now but it'll be the first thing to do when I wake up :) ...thanks again..i'll keep you updated ..